# express app and socket.io chat in different port?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My question is simple:
Am I following good practices or respecting standards if I set my chat with socket.io in a different port of my express application? ...say  my app runs on 4000 for all routes (`http://example.com:4000`, `http://example.com:4000/contact` ,...)  then I create in one of "this" routes but since my socket.io run on 3000 should it be now: `http://example.com:3000/chatroom`, then of course I set my namespace for my chat client like

```
  var nsp = io.of('/chatroom');
```

Am I doing it right? If not, please point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is ... I try both , in same port and in different and as long as you set a specific namespace for your chatroom you barely notice any change in performance .
Still , I have not made any test with concurrency in different and same port, cannot tell what happens when there are many users.